# Jquery change href attribute only works when I add an alert() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, timing

I am using jquery to load a sidebar into each of my pages, the sidebar contains a list of story names, the date, and the content type (story, article, news, whatever) which is placed in an unordered list, when each page loads I use jquery's .load() function to load the sidebar information into the current page's unordered list, once the sidebar information has loaded I use another script which sets the href of the current story in the sidebar to #. The problem is that the piece of code that sets the href to # only works if I put an alert right before the function.

Here is the flow:

user clicks on a story (lets call the story nothing.html)

**nothing.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../css/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../js/storyLoadSidebar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../js/disableLink.js"></script>
    <title> Nothing </title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="main">

            <article>

                <header>
                    <h3> Nothing Here </h3>
                    <time pubdate="pubdate"> July 19, 2011 </time>
                </header>

                <p> I said there was nothing here, yet. </p>

            </article>

        </div>

        <div id="listWrapper">
            <div id="storyList">
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**storyLoadSidebar.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul").load("../../../../sidebar.html ul");
});
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>  

    <ul>

        <li>
            <div class="catDate">
                <p> Nothing </p>
                <time pubdate="pubdate"> 2011-07-19 </time>
            </div>

            <div class="storyTitle">
                <a id="nothing" href="stories/2011/07/19/nothing.html"> Nothing Here, Yet. </a>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

then finally the script to disable the link:

**disableLink.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fullPath = window.location.pathname;
    var pageName = fullPath.substring(fullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).replace('.html', '');
    $('#' + pageName).attr('href', '#');
});
```

The entire thing only works of I add an alert to disableLink.js right before the href modification like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fullPath = window.location.pathname;
    var pageName = fullPath.substring(fullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).replace('.html', '');
    alert('now it will work');
    $('#' + pageName).attr('href', '#');
});
```

What is the problem here, why does it only work if I add in an alert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `$("ul").load("...")` takes some time to load.

You can assign it a call back function so the next piece of code only runs when it is completed

```
$("ul").load("../../../../sidebar.html ul",function () {
   var fullPath = window.location.pathname;
   var pageName = fullPath.substring(fullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).replace('.html', '');
   $('#' + pageName).attr('href', '#');
})
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much, I was wondering if there was a nice way to have both of these functions in one file without needing to pass any params, this works perfectly and I learned about callback functions, awesome! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes in this way you have all of it in the same file